# Angular ui-select2 - hide initial drawing/rendering of component

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, jquery-select2

I'm evaluating using Angular with ui-select2 and wondered whether someone could provide help on hiding the flicker/conversion of the `<select>` into the select2 component.

It's only very brief, but users can see the component change styles.

Is there a way of hiding it until the select has been modified by select2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the same problem and I had a look at the source code. The directive is deliberately initialised later by using a timeout. In the code there is a comment saying "Initialize the plugin late so that the injected DOM does not disrupt the template compiler".

My solution (you can see it in this jsplunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fXjDxs?p=preview ) is to set the visibility of the select tag to "hidden".

```
<select ui-select2 ng-model="....." style="visibility: hidden; ">......
```

When the component is loaded that tag is replaced with a div. In ui-select2.js I have added a line (line 208) to set its visibility to "visible".

```
elm.prev().css({"visibility": "visible"});
```

Comment: the `visibility:hidden` css is copied to the new div. any ideas?

Comment: You're right. I was using an old version. I have set up a jsplunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fXjDxs?p=preview . My solution is to keep the "visibility:hidden" in the select and I added a line of code in ui-select2.js (line 208) to change the visibility of the div when the component is loaded.

Comment: which is what I've ended up doing :) - i've actually added a line to the ui-select2 directive to ensure it's visible. thanks!